# Convert date of birth to age

Tags: r

I want to convert date of birth to age using the following code

```
df$age <- round(as.numeric(Sys.Date()-as.Date(df$DOB),format="%d/%m/%y")/365)
```

The format of DOB is f.e. 11-10-1969.

In the dataframe I see an age of 2012 (instead of 52).

I really dont know what I've done wrong. Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"11-10-1969" (month day year or day month year) is not an unambiguous date format. To get it properly converted you will need to specify the `format` argument to `as.Date()`

Note also that a 4-digit year needs a capital Y in the format string: "%d-%m-%Y" (or "%d/%m/%Y" for /). `Sys.Date()` is already a Date object, so you don't need the format argument with the `/`s in it.

```r
> as.numeric(Sys.Date() - as.Date("11-10-1969", format="%d-%m-%Y")) / 365.25
#> [1] 52.56674
```

EDIT: use 365.25 to approximate leap years per Henry's suggestion in comment

Comment: Probably worth dividing by 365.25 though there are more accurate methods

Comment: Thank you! Now it works,  but I see a lot of 'NA' in the data. F.e. 12-2-1938 = 83 and 14-2-1937 is NA. Can you explain this?

Comment: Ah, sorry, day month year! I edited my post. You just needed to put your `format` argument inside as.Date() and change the `/` to `-`

Comment: Thank you. Now there are several NA's in the column due to fase DOB. Can I remove them so that I can use the column right away for example in a glm? I tried things linke !is.na(data$age) but this doesn't work. Or do I have to make a new column for this?